# python - iterating over a list to format

Tags: python

```
list = [0.0, .1234567, 0.0, .45678, .4, .003]

for i in list:
    print('{:5.f2}'.format(i))
```

This gives 'ValueError: Format Specifier missing precision' No idea what that means.
The print line looks as it should to me so what have I got wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to print up to 2 decimal places?

Comment: `'{:5.2f}'` is what you want

Comment: *Format Specifier* is the `{:5.f2}` expression you're using to format the value you want to print, and *'Format Specifier missing precision'* means that `'{:5.f2}'` is a typo, it can't find the precision (number of decimal places) for the float, you're trying to pass it 2, you meant to write `{:5.2f}` instead. Please take a look at any good tutorial on formatting in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is `#.#f`:

```
print('{:5.2f}'.format(i))
```